# Create ArrayList from array using temporary object

Tags: java, arraylist

I know there are standard way by add a constructors to the class. But for classes with object superclass (has no-argument constructor) I tend to find using a temporary object simpler. Is there any down side for such an act.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class Main { 

      public static void main(String[] args){

        // data available in two separated arrays  
        String[] dName = {"Sam","Ben","Joye","Sarah","Tim","Lucy","Jack"} ;
        int[] dAge= {10,52,53,15,12,60,21};

        // Array list to put the data in 
        ArrayList<Person> personList =new ArrayList<Person>(7);

        for (int i=0;i<dName.length;i++){
            Person tempPerson = new Person();
            tempPerson.name= dName[i];
            tempPerson.age= dAge[i];
            personList.add(new Person());
            personList.set(i,tempPerson);
            tempPerson=null;    //removes the reference
        }

        for (int j=0 ; j<personList.size();j++){
            System.out.println(personList.get(j).name+" age is "+personList.get(j).age );
        }

      }  
    }

class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

the output

```
Sam age is 10
Ben age is 52
Joye age is 53
Sarah age is 15
Tim age is 12
Lucy age is 60
Jack age is 21
```

Comment: Why are you first adding `new Person()` to the list and after that `tempPerson`? Also, no need to remove the reference - it will be 'free' after every loop cycle.

Comment: First, I did not understand your question. Do you want to automatically create an ArrayList<Person> from the two arrays? Second, that object management in the for-loop is a bit weird. Why adding the new Person() to the ArrayList and then setting tempPerson to null?

Comment: yes right, You meant it will free every loop since it is constructed again. I thought it would better to destroy before renew again.

Comment: pca, new refrence needed in each loop otherwise the whole lost will be same values (last arrays values) since the list will have same object references.

Comment: Not really. You create the object, and then you add it to the list. At this point the object is referenced by tempPerson and the list. When you do tempPerson = new Person(); the array will still hold the previous object. Just like you have it in Jan's answer.

Comment: yes that was my meaning in new reference is needed in each loop,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid statements that do nothing - an optimization would be to do

```
   for (int i=0;i<dName.length;i++){
        Person tempPerson = new Person();
        tempPerson.name= dName[i];
        tempPerson.age= dAge[i];
        personList.add(tempPerson);
    }
```

- No need to first add the person to later replace it
- No need to null the reference - the list will keep the reference to the temp object in any case.
- Instead of setting values directly you could use setters (`setName()` instead of `.name =` )
- If you'd use setters, you could implement a Builder pattern:

like this:

```
 public Person setName(String aName) {
   name = aName;
   return this;
 }
```

Resulting in something like

```
 personList.add(new Person().setName(dName[i]).setAge(dAge[i]));
```

Then again - the two value constructor will probably be the easiest of all - and it don't matter that the super class doesn't have a constructor:

```
public Person(String aName, int aAge) {
   name = aName;
   age = aAge;
}
//You can have more than one constructor
public Person() {
}
```

and then

```
personList.add(new Person(dName[i], sAge[i]));
```

Comment: thanks, i just thought i needed to destroy the object reference before initialize again. I tried direct add first time but it was trouble (looks like something else was wrong) so i thought i need to construct with add(new and then i can Set the value..
thanks again it is perfect now

Answer (score 3):

You should use a constructor for Person. Then you have just one call in your for-loop:

```
personList.add(new Person(dName[i], dAge[i])
```

Also, in your implementation, you are doing the necessary work twice, because you call `personList.add(new Person())` and then you call `personList.set(i, temPerson)`. If you don't want a constructor in your Person-class, a call of `personList.add(tempPerson)` for example would be enough.

Comment: Yes of course the constructor will be more convenience but sometimes it is little easier to use a temp object. Yes .add( and .set( later is no needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really,

you could maybe make use of java8 streams, but why make your life harder, it wouldnt add anything new